# Multiple dates & amount adjacent to each other in same row

Tags: excel

I tried the formula provided by you, but for only 2 rows I am getting the answers, for othes error is shown as attached[enter image[enter image description here][1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/U6yOz.png) description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6zPJZ.jpg)

For Example
Cell AH36 = 11-Sept-2014 & Cell AI36 = $14590 & Cell AJ36 = 21-Sept-2014 & Cell AK36 = $11890 & Cell AL36 = 9-Nov-2014 & Cell AM = $29179 & Cell AN36 = 15-Nov-2014 & Cell AO = $43769 & Cell AP36 = 29-Nov-2014 & Cell AQ = $14590

I should get automatically the data in same row (even if in different column) For Sept-2014 the total amount should be $26480 ($14590 + $11890) & similarly in the same row for Nov 2014 the total amount should be $ 87535 ($29179 + $43769 + $14590)

Please note that the above is an example only. I will be having data's in multiple rows & for each rows with different dates/month/year will be having different amounts.

Comment: table screen shot attached

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Example:

[image]

Formula in `A4`:

```
=SUMPRODUCT((MOD(COLUMN($F4:$X4),2)=0)*(DATE($A$2,A$3,1)<=$F4:$X4)*(DATE($A$2,A$3+1,1)>$F4:$X4)*$G4:$Y4)
```

The approach:

`(MOD(COLUMN($F4:$X4),2)=0)` is `TRUE` (1) for even (not odd) columns only.

`(DATE($A$2,A$3,1)<=$F4:$X4)*(DATE($A$2,A$3+1,1)>$F4:$X4)` is `TRUE` (1) if the dates are within the needed month.

`$G4:$Y4` takes the values one column shifted to the dates.

In `SUMPRODUCT` the single conditions will be multiplied:

`(MOD(COLUMN($F4:$X4),2)=0)*(DATE($A$2,A$3,1)<=$F4:$X4)*(DATE($A$2,A$3+1,1)>$F4:$X4)`

So only if all conditions are `TRUE` (1), the multiplication is 1, otherwise 0.

So at last the `*$G4:$Y4` leads to only the values for which all conditions are `TRUE`.

Comment: Thanks a lot. The formula provided by you is working. Please let me know why " * " sign was put in between. i couldn't understand that logic. it will help me to understand the complete formula.

Comment: The `*` is simply multiplication. See my supplements.

Comment: In case if there are no data in some of the rows, the result is coming as #VALUE!. any help to overcome this?

Comment: If the result is `#VALUE!` then in that row there is text instead of values. You can wrap the formula in a `IFERROR`, like: `=IFERROR(SUMPRODUCT((MOD(COLUMN($F4:$X4),2)=0)*(DATE($A$2,A$3,1)<=$F4:$X4)*(DATE($A$2,A$3+1,1)>$F4:$X4)*$G4:$Y4),"")`

Comment: I am still having problem in formula working. i had already attached the screen shot for the same. please help

Comment: As stated already, somewhere in `AI35:BA35` is text instead of a value. Thats why the multiplication `*AI35:BA35` returns the `#VALUE!` error. Please check this. If you have `=IF(...., "")` or `=IFERROR(...., "")` as formulas there: `""` is also text. You need `0` there instead of `""`.

Comment: I got it, its working. Appreciate your help & patience.

Comment: Please let me know the formula in excel 2013 - If any of the multiple cells of a row is blank it should show the cell ref. I had tried with the below formula which is working fine but the formula is very long. is there any other way to cut short this formula??

Comment: (IF($B17="","Pls enter PO Ref",IF($C17="","Pls enter Supplier",IF($D17="","Pls enter Brief Description",IF($G17="","Pls enter Item No.",IF($N17="","Pls enter Del Period",IF($O17="","Pls enter Del UOM",IF(ISTEXT($P17),"Error Del Data",IF($Q17="","Pls Check ETA",IF($R17="","Pls select ETA Location",IF($W17="","Pls enter PO Date",IF($X17="","Pls select PO Currency",IF($Z17="","Pls enter PO Amount",IF($AC17="","Pls enter Payment Terms",""))))))))))))))